# Why Facebook Send button not displaying?

Tags: javascript, facebook, button

Sorry I have reposted this question. Couldn't delete this one.

[When I click the Facebook Send button, the div is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045642/when-i-click-the-facebook-send-button-the-div-is-not-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure if this is related to the specific bug, but there is definitely a significant bug with the Send button right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/263204287096105?browse=search_4f7e78b951f6d6f43844112

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. I don't think it's related to that. It's just that the div does not appear when I click the Send button. I have followed all the instructions,but it doesn't work anymore. Regards

Comment: Yes I did but with no success. I am modifying my original post. I have tried the simplest example with a html template file and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! did u manage to fix the problem? I am having the same problem