# When I click the Facebook Send button, the div is not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

For some reason, when I click the Facebook Send button, the button changes its color, as to say it was clicked (this is normal), but the div does not appear.

I am giving you a simple example below. It doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know what mistake I made? Thanks a lot

My code is the following:

EDIT: All I did was copy and paste what the Facebook documentation tells me to paste.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=276966272386423";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://apple.com"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I see that are not using jQuery or Dojo un you js, you should check those tools.

Any way, can you put the code of the element with the id "facebook-jssdk" you are doing `document.getElementById("facebook-jssdk")` I can not see that element exist. With the code that you put this script will fail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Please go to http://jsfiddle.net/sD43y/
 and try this script. It works there but doesn't work on any of my computer with the exact same html file.

Comment: Have checked the console to ensure that no access restrictions are being reported?

Comment: The example code at jsfiddle.net/sD43y works perfectly, when the button is clicked, the link is messaged to the people I chose.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Was a solution found?